# Python Can't Insert Data to SQLITE3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi, esp8266

I am trying to complete a project where an ESP8266 sends DHT22 data to a Raspberry Pi and then the Pi implements the data to a sqlite database via a Python Script. Then the script pulls up the data from the database and inserts it into an HTML webpage which then becomes a web server. I am using this tutorial: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-publishing-dht22-readings-to-sqlite-database/#comment-355609

The ESP successfully send the DHT data to the PI as I am able to see it on the output. Also, the HTML web page displays manually entered SQLite data but Python can't insert any data to the database.

(Couldn't paste the code because of formatting issues. I am new to this site.)
Thank you.

Comment: read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I've created the table via command line.

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO dhtreadings (temperature,
        humidity, currentdate, currentime, device) VALUES((?), (?), date('now'),
        time('now'), (?))""", (dhtreadings_json['temperature'],
        dhtreadings_json['humidity'], 'esp8266') )
```

and used currenttime instead of currentime shown on the original code. I can't believe this; such a small detail ruined my whole day. Also I think currenttime is the correct version since its correct English-wise.